Performance difference between C-Contiguous and Fortran-Contiguous arrays while using numpy functions
I was working around an example from a book compairing performance between  C-Contiguous and Fortran-Contiguous arrays, where i observed that the Fortran-Contiguous array performed better for row-wise operations than C-Contiguous array when using np.sum(axis=1) ie. opposite of what should be expected. While using np.cumsum(axis=1) performance of C-contiguous array was better as expected theoretically. What could be the reason?
The Jupyter Notebook code:
import numpy as np
arr_c=np.ones((1000,1000),order='C')
arr_f=np.ones((1000,1000),order='F')

The observed results were just opposite of what should be expected theoretically when used np.sum(axis=1).
%timeit arr_c.sum(axis=1)

605 µs ± 40.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit arr_f.sum(axis=1)

398 µs ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
However the results were as expected when used np.cumsum(axis=1).
%timeit arr_c.cumsum(axis=1)

4.01 ms ± 83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit arr_f.cumsum(axis=1)

15.6 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Did this book focus in numpy?  or at least some sort of stride based multidimensionality?  Did it discuss memory paging and caches?

What happens with smaller arrays, say (50,50)?  Here memory access details will be less significant.

The book focused on Numpy but didnt really talked about memory paging or caches.The behaviour is similar as observed above for smaller and larger arrays both checked from (50,50) to (10000,10000).

Paging and caching depends on processors, memory size, and compilers. All of which differ with users, and over time.  Basically these are implementation details.

Numpy can compute the sum line by line. AFAIK it does this for einsum so I would not be surprised if this is also done for basic sums. AFAIK such optimizations are not done for more complex functions and cumsum is an example of more complex one. As long as you do not know the implementation, the discussion about the performance of C vs Fortran ordering is not very relevant. Besides, note that the implementation can change over time (for the sake of performance). Looking the implementation and profiling it is the key to answer this question properly.

I don't which book you are referring to. But I think either the book is wrong, either you misread it (or it is in a particular context, and is talking about some other consideration than the one I have in mind). But people are usually taught in HPC lessons is that C order is better when the inner part of your algorithm iterates columns, and Fortran when inner part iterates rows.
Why order change performance
Firstly (I suppose this is what your book says) it is important to understand why order is important. This is because of cache memory. If your algorithm access data in order in which they are stored, then, most of the time, the data is already in cache memory. If not, then, you'll have to retrieve a new block from memory more often, which costs.
So, if memory contains M₀=0 M₁=1 M₂=2 M₃=3 M₄=4 M₅=5 M₆=6 M₇=7 M₈=8 M₉=9 M₁₀=10 M₁₁=11 M₁₂=12 M₁₃=13 M₁₄=14 M₁₅=15, then algorithm
s=0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        s+=Mᵢₓ₄₊ⱼ

is more efficient than
s=0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        s+=Mⱼₓ₄₊ᵢ

Because the first one access M₀, M₂, ..., M₁₅ in that order, when the second one accesses M₀, M₄, M₈, M₁₂, M₁, M₅, ...
If your memory cache hold only 4 M places, then 1st version will have to reload a block only 4 times, which second version will have to get a new block each 16 times.
Of course, that is a theoretical example. Cache are bigger than that. But that is the reason.
Now, if we assume that those 16 memory places are the 16 data of a matrix M[row, colum], if you are summing just one column ("just one" is important here) of a matrix M[row, colum], let say column 1,
def sumColumn(col):
    s=0
    for row in range(4):
        s+=M[row, col]
sumColumn(1)

Would access to memory M₄, M₅, M₆, M₇ is matrix is in Fortran order (so M[i,j] is at memory Mᵢ₊₄ⱼ)
But would access to memory M₁,M₅,M₉,M₁₃ is matrix is in C order (so M[i,j] is at memory M₄ᵢ₊ⱼ)
Why it is not applicable directly to whole matrix operations
If implementation of sum(axis=1) is equivalent of
result=np.zeros((4,))
for column in range(4):
    result[column] = sumColumn(column)

That is, if I unroll it
result=np.zeros((4,))
for column in range(4):
    for row in range(4):
        result[column] += M[row, column]

Then, it is 4 times the same thing. So 4 times an algorithm that is efficient in Fortran order, less so in C order
But nothing says that this is the implementation
It could also be
result=np.zeros((4,))
for row in range(4):
    for column in range(4):
        result[column] += M[row, column]

And then you get an algorithm that is more efficient (cache-wise) in C order than in Fortran order.
So, point is, it is implementation dependent. So implementation are better when data are in C order (because they iterate row first, column second, that is in memory order data are in C order). And some are better when data are in Fortran order (because they iterate column fist, row second, that is in memory order if data are in Fortran order).
And you can bet that numpy uses the best implementation for each context, when possible.
tl;dr
Usually when people talk about performance related to order, it is because of cache. And cache-wise, summing a single column is faster if data are in Fortran order (and all data of the column are adjacent in memory).
But that doesn't apply to summing all columns, like .sum(axis=1) or np.cumsum(axis=1) do,  because you don't know if the implementation iterates row first column second.

In numpy multidimensionality is implemented via shape and strides attributes.  In the examples, the underlying base array is the same C array.  One has strides (4000,4) (float32 windows), the other (4,4000).  In theory strided math like this should have similar perfromance, but (1000,1000) is large enough that caching can make a big difference in performance - and it will be hard to predict.

Indeed. But that is what I was trying to say. for row in...: doSomething with arr[row, col] becomes for row in ...: doSomething with what is in base(row*stride1+col*stride2). Which are contiguous data if stride1 is small, not if stride1 is big. That the whole point. And cache line sizes are, even with modern cpu with plenty of cache, very small (128 bytes for the highest). So it really changes something. Even with a 10x10 array of float64, iterating every 10 floats, so every 80 bytes in memory, or iterating every floats, that is every 8 bytes, is not the same, cache-wise.

With a stride1 (with my previous notation) of 80, iterating 1 column of that 10x10 array of float64 means that you need to load a cache line 5 times. With a stride1=8, only once. But of course, if you do that for the whole matrix, since you have many cache lines, ... and since you would need to have everything sooner or later in one of them, it doesn't change. Unless the matrix is so big, that you run out of cache line before you can reuse one.

Anyway. I didn't want to go into details. Point is, reading data in the order in which they are in memory is generally speaking better. Way better, if you don't read all data eventually or if the don't fill all in cache. Only slightly better otherwise. But never worse.

Thank you for your response  ,I really appreciate it. The book i was referring to is -Python for Data Analysis: Data Wrangling with pandas, NumPy, and Jupyter 3rd Edition by Wes McKinney ( link- https://wesmckinney.com/book/ ). The content could be found on the  Appendix A — Advanced NumPy section.
